# How to remove data from firebase and also in array in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm completely new to firebase and I would like to know how can I remove ad by using title (or atleast a key?)

This is how I managed to transfer firebase data to array :

```
componentDidMount(){
      firebase.database().ref('/ads').on('value', (snapshot) =>{
        var list = []
        snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
         list.push({
          key: child.key,
          title:child.val().title,
          details: child.val().details
        })
      })
     this.setState({adlist:list})
    })
   }
```

This is how I displayed on the FlatList (display works):

```
 <FlatList 
            data={this.state.adlist}
            keyExtractor={(item)=>item.title}
            renderItem={({item})=>{
               return(
                <TouchableOpacity  OnPress ={()=>deleteAd(item.title)}>
                <View style={styles.container_2}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_style1}>{item.title}</Text>
                     <Text>{item.details}</Text>
                </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
               )}}/>
```

The function that I made to delete it from firebase

```
DeleteAds = (title)=>{
      dispatch(deleteAd(title));

    }
```

That's leads to this function

```
export const deleteAd = (title) => {
  return(dispatch)=>{
    firebase.database().ref('/ads/' + title).remove();
   
  }
```

My firebase database looks like this:
[image]

When I click the button it's doesn't delete from firebase nor from array .Basically nothing happens.

I will greateful if you find the way to improve my delete function or maybe how I should pass firebase data to array so I could able to delete with a key.

Comment: I also tried doing firebase.database().ref('/ads').remove();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to delete the node by it's title. So if you delete the first node, with title `dfdsd`, you're deleting the path `/ads/dfdsd`, which doesn't exist.

To delete a node, you need to know its key. So you should:

1. Render the key into the HTML, typically in a way that isn't visible to the user.
2. Then pass that key to the `deleteAd` function, instead of the title.

In code:

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.state.adlist}
    keyExtractor={(item)=>item.key}
    renderItem={({item})=>{
       return(
        <TouchableOpacity  OnPress ={()=>deleteAd(item.key)}>
        <View style={styles.container_2}>
            <Text style={styles.text_style1}>{item.title}</Text>
             <Text>{item.details}</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       )}}/>
```

You'll note I also modified the `keyExtractor={(item)=>item.key}`, since that should probably also be based on the key of the node instead of its title.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Perheps can you suggest how can I extract key from database, and store to array ? I'm currently having trouble with it.